# Remove event with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following at html code

```
<a class="toolbar" onclick="javascript: submitbutton('items')" href="#">
```

Now i want that in jquery i convert it to

```
 <a class="toolbar" href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like that?

```
$('.toolbar').removeAttr('onclick').attr('href','javascript:history.go(-1)');
```

Comment: Look up documentation? Search through SO first before posing a question? Searching for something like 'remove attribute jquery' reveals may hits on SO and Google that match your question. http://www.google.com/search?q=remove+attribute+jquery http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+attribute+jquery

Comment: Also, you don't need the "javascript:" in there. onclick will work just fine without it.

Comment: ACtually i didn't knew that onclick was attribute , i thought it was event so i was looking for removing event